# Getting an error "__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"

Tags: php, class

I am assigning the object for class "PurchOrder" to session variable

```
$_SESSION['obj'] = new PurchOrder;
```

But it returns the error "__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name" when i access the function which is inside the class "PurchOrder"

I didnt handle this type of error before.

Answer (score 2):

This happens if the `PurchOrder` class is not available when you are using the object stored in the session (or in any other case where a class instance is serialized and unserialized).

You need to ensure  that whatever file defines that class is included whenever you want to use an instance of it.

Comment: First time it works fine . When I access the object once again then it shows that error.

Comment: Then the class is not available when you access it the second time.

Comment: yes, but i cannot create obj once again because it will remove the existing value for that class

Comment: You are not supposed to create the object again, you just have to make sure the *class* is available, i.e. whatever files contains the `class PurchOrder { ... }` code needs to be included.